# How to update reference object in Spring-data rest?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest

**Example:** class Course and Teacher having many-to-one relationship, how to change teacher for a certain course via Spring-data rest?

```
GET http://localhost:7070/study-spring-data/course/2
```

Response:

```
{
  "name" : "CSCI-338 Hardcore Java",
  "_links" : [ {
    "rel" : "course.Course.teacher",
    "href" : "http://localhost:7070/study-spring-data/course/2/teacher"
  }, {
    "rel" : "self",
    "href" : "http://localhost:7070/study-spring-data/course/2"
  } ]
}

GET http://localhost:7070/study-spring-data/course/2/teacher
```

Response:

```
{
  "_links" : [ {
    "rel" : "course.Course.teacher",
    "href" : "http://localhost:7070/study-spring-data/course/2/teacher/1"
  } ]
}
```

As above shown, course 2 is associated with teacher 1, how to change teacher to teacher 2?

**I have tried:**

successfully updated course name:

`PUT http://localhost:7070/study-spring-data/course/2`
    with payload

```
    {
      "name" : "CSCI-223 Hardcore C++",
    }
```

**unsuccessful** when try to update reference object teacher:

```
PUT http://localhost:7070/study-spring-data/course/2/teacher
```

with payload

```
    {
      "_links" : [ {
        "rel" : "course.Course.teacher",
        "href" : "http://localhost:7070/study-spring-data/course/2/teacher/2"
      } ]
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: amazing! It actually worked. I thought payload only accept header with "application/json". I can't find this in spring-data document though. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" \
     -d "http://localhost:7070/study-spring-data/teacher/1" \
     http://localhost:7070/study-spring-data/course/123/teacher
```

This is a way suggested by O'Reilly's Spring Data book.

Comment: Ah, they made updating a single reference look like adding new references to a collection. That's why it uses text/uri-list even though there's no list involved.

Comment: *Why* would you do that? Wouldn't that mean that your client takes control over associations? What if your client forgets to do that?

Comment: is there any way to do it in JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to check the Cascading for Course. Because if you are updating the course , then it should update your teacher also, if Cascading update or All is to be assigned for your course.

Answer (score 0):

Using [httpie](https://httpie.org/) PATCH instead of PUT works for me:

```
http PATCH :7070/study-spring-data/course/2 teacher="http://localhost:7070/study-spring-data/teacher/2"
```

Again, this does not work with PUT.