# How to update entity with many to many relation using MockMvc?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test, mockmvc

I am writing simple spring-boot app and want to test it. I have `User` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User extends AbstractEntity {
    public enum Type {
        ADMIN, USER
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Type type;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String username;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "managers")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Set<Label> label;
}
```

And `Label` class (consider it's an organization, where `User` works):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "labels")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Label extends AbstractEntity {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String title;

    @OneToOne
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private User creator;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "label_managers")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Set<User> managers;
}
```

Those entities are managed by `@RepositoryRestResource`s.

What should I write in my test with `MockMvc` to add relation between a `User` and a `Label`?

Answer (score 0):

"By using "Content-Type: text/uri-list" instead of JSON, it is possible to "add" a resource to the collection with a PUT and pass in the URI. You can remove the resource with a DELETE."

Review the answer to the following question: [How to add elements in a many-to-many relationship via Spring's @RepositoryRestResource REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259474/how-to-add-elements-in-a-many-to-many-relationship-via-springs-repositoryrestr?)